How can you mock Puppet fileshare paths in Puppet Litmus?
I have a class that downloads files from a Puppet file share on the Puppet server:
file { '/opt/common/data.txt':
  ensure => file,
  source => 'puppet:///common/data.txt', # lint:ignore:puppet_url_without_modules
}

During testing with Litmus, this will fail since there isn't actually any file server to pull from.
Is there some way I can mock this file share with Puppet Litmus?

The most idiomatic way to test Puppet code is with RSpec, and what's generally tested that way is that the Puppet code under test produces the expected effects on the generated catalog.  I had no idea that Litmus had any support for Puppet at all.  In fact, Litmus wasn't even on my radar -- are you talking about the abandoned QA tool from Mozilla?  Whatever testing tool you use, you'll need to mock a lot more than a Puppet file server in order to test catalog application instead of catalog building.

Puppet Litmus is an acceptance testing tool from Puppet: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet_litmus
I'm already doing unit tests with RSpec. This is strictly for acceptance testing using serverspec.

Thanks for the clarification.  There is now a [puppet-litmus] tag.

I am not very familiar with Puppet Litmus, but it does not appear support any kind of mocking, per se.  If it can handle testing modules that rely on arbitrary Puppet fileserver paths then it looks like that would be by actually provisioning the test environment with appropriate fileserver configuration and files to be served.  I suspect that can be made to work, but I don't find any documentation of the details.
